Getting Error: (#100) Unexpected key \"format\" on param \"template['components'][0]\"
We have created a WhatsApp template and in that template, when a user registers on our platform, we will send him an SMS. The onboarding SMS template will have a video in the headerand below that, there will be content in the body.
To send video file, we have used video upload API and we get an upload ID from there.
When we are trying to hit the API from postman we are getting the following error.
{"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Unexpected key \"format\" on param \"template['components'][0]\".",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A-mwg-aEQpPILr2lqp14xbk"
}}

Below is the request body which we are sending in the POST API:
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"to": "91XXXXXXXX",
"type": "template",
"template": {
   "name": "user_onboarding",
   "language": {
       "code": "en"
   },
   "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "format": "VIDEO",
        "example": {
            "header_handle": [
            "4:eW9sb2hlYWx0aA==:dmlkZW8vbXA0:ARaoH5bTOjkT5kECygOVWZZYZKHfmSQJ3mnPyU7ZcMVa-7igCYeEcV2G-OurPYfHlxUlU2sWQwMO1wJDCBdTh2YnC4Jc1hgRU7-d4PoYJmJZrg:e:1723915181:528600102618885:100092379197505:ARYmumWHM2WJ0KJHFC4"
            ]
        }
     },
     {
       "type": "BODY",
       "parameters": [
           {
               "type": "text",
               "text": "Saif Khan"
           },
           {
               "type": "text",
               "text": "YoloHealth"
           }
       ]
     }
   ]
}

}
API URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/124449227309891/messages
Please check the images below for media upload.


Any help would be appreciated.

I took a quick peek at the meta docs here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/message-templates/media-message-templates/
In the context of the WhatsApp API for message templates, the "format" key should not be used directly in this way. So I suggest you remove the string "format": "VIDEO" from your request.
{
"messaging_product": "whatsapp",
"to": "91XXXXXXXX",
"type": "template",
"template": {
    "name": "user_onboarding",
    "language": {
        "code": "en"
    },
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "header",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "video",
                    "video": {
                        "id": "your_video_upload_id"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "body",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Saif Khan"
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "YoloHealth"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

}

Thanks a lot Hafiz, You almost solve my issue. After changing a litle bit in JSON as mentioned by you we are getting this error now  (#100) Param template['components'][0]['parameters'][0]['video']['id'] is not a valid whatsapp business account media attachment ID".

What request do you use to download media? And what is the response?

Hey Hafiz, Please check the edited question. I am using two API's for uploading media and getting the video Id.
